# maven project + wildfly + deploy .war

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly

note :Im new in dev with Javaee.
My problem it's seems simple but i couldn't understand it, i have created a simple Maven Project  and when i try to build it in maven and writing "wildfly:deploy" i got a problem of deploying the "".war and this is the .log:

```
Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."pfeweb.war".component.AlimentationBD.START: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."pfeweb.war".component.AlimentationBD.START: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYEE0042: Failed to construct component instance

15:26:18,891 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:19990/management
15:26:18,892 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:19990
15:26:18,892 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0026: WildFly Full 9.0.1.Final (WildFly Core 1.0.1.Final) started (with errors) in 15180ms - Started 362 of 540 services (5 services failed or missing dependencies, 221 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
15:26:18,969 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 18) WFLYJPA0011: Stopping Persistence Unit (phase 2 of 2) Service 'pfeweb.war#pfe-ejb'
15:26:18,980 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYWELD0010: Stopping weld service for deployment pfeweb.war
15:26:18,981 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 18) WFLYJPA0011: Stopping Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'pfeweb.war#pfe-ejb'
15:26:19,051 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment pfeweb.war (runtime-name: pfeweb.war) in 104ms
15:26:19,196 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYSRV0009: Undeployed "pfeweb.war" (runtime-name: "pfeweb.war")
15:26:19,198 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0184:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.deployment.unit."pfeweb.war".WeldStartService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./pfeweb, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./pfeweb.UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."pfeweb.war".component.AlimentationBD.START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."pfeweb.war".moduleDeploymentRuntimeInformationStart, service jboss.deployment.unit."pfeweb.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./pfeweb, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./pfeweb.UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."pfeweb.war".component.AuthentificationService.START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."pfeweb.war".moduleDeploymentRuntimeInformationStart, service jboss.deployment.unit."pfeweb.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./pfeweb, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./pfeweb.UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."pfeweb.war".component."Beans.AccessBean".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."pfeweb.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./pfeweb, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./pfeweb.UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."pfeweb.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."pfeweb.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./pfeweb, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./pfeweb.UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."pfeweb.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."pfeweb.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./pfeweb, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./pfeweb.UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."pfeweb.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."pfeweb.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./pfeweb, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./pfeweb.UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."pfeweb.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."pfeweb.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./pfeweb, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./pfeweb.UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."pfeweb.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldInitialListener".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."pfeweb.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./pfeweb, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./pfeweb.UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."pfeweb.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldTerminalListener".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."pfeweb.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./pfeweb, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./pfeweb.UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."pfeweb.war".ee.ComponentRegistry (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./pfeweb.UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."pfeweb.war".moduleDeploymentRuntimeInformation (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."pfeweb.war".moduleDeploymentRuntimeInformationStart] 
      service jboss.persistenceunit."pfeweb.war#pfe-ejb" (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."pfeweb.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./pfeweb, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./pfeweb.UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
      service jboss.server.global-request-controller.control-point."pfeweb.war".undertow (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./pfeweb.UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
      service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./pfeweb (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."pfeweb.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./pfeweb.UndertowDeploymentInfoService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./pfeweb] 
      service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./pfeweb.codec (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./pfeweb.UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
      service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./pfeweb.session (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./pfeweb.UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."pfeweb.war".component.AlimentationBD.START

15:26:23,416 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDS0004: Found pfeweb.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called pfeweb.war.dodeploy
```

can someone help me please

Comment: Something's wrong with your `AlimentationBD` bean, which seems like an EJB of some sort.

Comment: You need to show the section of the log that is above `Services which failed to start` because that will normally contain more useful information

Comment: Hello again 
this is the section where is the problem:

Comment: [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
NFO] Total time: 20.409 s
[INFO] Final Memory: 15M/201M

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.wildfly.plugins:wildfly-maven-plugin:1.0.2.Final:deploy (default-cli) on project pfeweb: Could not execute goal deploy on C:\Users\Amine_Info\workspace\pfeweb\target\pfeweb.war. Reason: I/O Error could not execute operation '{
[ERROR] "operation" => "read-attribute",
[ERROR] "address" => [],
[ERROR] "name" => "launch-type"
[ERROR] }': java.net.ConnectException: JBAS012174: Could not connect to http-remoting://127.0.0.1:9990. The connection failed: Invalid response

Comment: and i got this problem too when i do fullpublish of the "pfeweb.war" in the server :
NSTALL: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "pfeweb.war" service jboss.deployment.unit."pfeweb.war".INSTALL

Answer (score 0):

```
This is pom.xml of the war project 
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>tn.orange.pfe</groupId>
<artifactId>pfeweb</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>tn.orange.pfe</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <artifactId>pfeejb</artifactId>
        <type>ejb</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>5.2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
            <configuration>
                <hostname>localhost</hostname>
                <port>18181</port>
                <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, you might have some conflicting API's(specifically javax.servlet-api here).

> try by changing the scope in pom.xml, the **provided** scope will only put dependency while compile time, and the dependency will not conflict at runtime, with the Wildfly provided default javax servlet dependency.

like:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

by this , the servlet api you are providing , will not conflict with the one provided by the server, and the dependency will only be present while compile time.
(P.S - the server also provides javax.servlet), if you have already used `maven install` , just delete your `javax.servlet-api` from library and do `maven install` again